# Google Chrome Printing issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, printing

I am having problems that are specific to Google Chrome. It is a confirmation page for an order. On print preview, it shows up fine. When I actually print the page however, all of the text is just random symbols and makes no sense. I am using UTF-8 just like all the other pages that work fine. I am officially stumped on this one.

Here is the HTML for the page:

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ include file="/shared/components/imageCacheUrl.jsp" %> 

<!doctype html>
<!--[if lte IE 6 ]><html lang="en" id="ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang="en" id="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en" id="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html lang="en" id="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 10)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>Delta.com - Donate Miles Confirmation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<s:url value="/buyGiftTransfer/css/buygifttransferdonate.css"/>' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<s:url value="/buyGiftTransfer/css/donateCss.css"/>' />
</head>
<body class="no-js">
    <jsp:include page="../../tmpl/breadcrumbs/index.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <h1 class="bgt-headerTxt">Donate Miles</h1>
    <div id="ContentWell" class="grid_9 alpha bgt-app">
        <div id="bgt-primarymodule" class="contentWrapper clearfix">
            <div id="bgt-primarymodule-container">
                <!--<jsp:include page="../../tmpl/donate/_primaryModule.tmpl.jsp"></jsp:include>-->
                <!-- fix for Defect ID 10345 -->
                <h2 class="marketingTitle">DONATE MILES. MAKE A DIFFERENCE</h2>
                <p>Not sure what to do with your SkyMiles? Donate them to charity. Whichever charity or charities you choose, your miles will be put to good use. Please read the need-to-knows list before donating.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>All donations to SkyWish and SkyWish Asia charities are not tax deductible for SkyMiles members or Delta.</li>
                    <li>Maximum of five charities can be selected and processed in one transaction.</li>
                    <li>Once the transaction has been completed, the miles will be transferred to the selected charities and cannot be reversed.</li>
                    <li>SkyMiles account must have sufficient miles to donate. </li>
                    <li>Minimum mileage donation rules apply.  Select individual charity for details.</li>  
                </ul>

            </div>
            <s:fielderror template="inlineerrors" />
        </div>
            <div id="recieptModule" class="contentWrapper">
                <h2 class="contentWrapperHeader">CONFIRMATION</h2>
                <div>
                    <ul id="emailPrint">
                        <li id="print"><a href="javascript:window.print()" class="ir">Print</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="sub_container_6">
                    <div class="sub_grid_4 alpha">
                        <hgroup>
                            <h2 class="marketingTitle">Thanks, <strong mpdistrans><s:property value="donateMiles.donateMilesProductType.name.firstName" /> <s:property value="donateMiles.donateMilesProductType.name.lastName" /></strong></h2>
                            <h4 class="marketingSubtitle">for your generous donation of <strong><s:text name="format.number"><s:param value="donateMiles.donateMilesProductType.totalDonateMilesAmount"></s:param></s:text> miles</strong> to these charities:</h4>
                        </hgroup>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub_grid_2 omega">
                        <p id="transactionDate">Transaction Date: <s:property value="donateMiles.donateMilesProductType.transactionDate" /></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <s:iterator value="donateMiles.donateMilesProductType.donateMilesProductResponses">
                        <div class="addedCharityDeets clearfix">
                            <div class="sub_grid_4 alpha">
                                <h4 class="recipientOrgName" mpdistrans>
                                    <s:property value="donateMilesProduct.recipientOrg.description" />
                                    <s:if test="fault.error.errorCode != 0000">
                                        &nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;<s:property value="fault.error.errorMsg"/>
                                    </s:if> 
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sub_grid_1 giftedSkyMiles">
                                <p class="label">Donated Miles</p>
                                <p class="value"><s:text name="format.number"><s:param value="donateMilesProduct.recipientOrg.milesToDonate"></s:param></s:text><!--20,000 Miles--></p>
<!--                                <div class="grid_4 push_4">
                                        <div class="callout">
                                            <p class="infoicon promoicon">Applied</p>
                                            <div class="infoMessage">
                                                <h5>Promotion</h5>
                                                <p>100% matching miles.</p>
                                                <p><a href="#">See Details</a></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
-->                             </div>  
                                <s:if test="donateMilesProduct.estimateBonusMiles != 0">
                                <div class="sub_grid_1 omega lastcolumn">
                                    <h5 class="label">Bonus Miles</h5>
                                    <p><s:property value="donateMilesProduct.estimateBonusMiles" /></p>
                                </div>
                            </s:if>
                        </div>
                    </s:iterator>

                    <div id="thankyouMessage" class="sub_grid_3 alpha">
                        <s:if test="donateMiles.donateMilesProductType.totalBonusMiles != 0">
                            <p>As a thank you, we are crediting your account with <s:property value="donateMiles.donateMilesProductType.totalBonusMiles" /> bonus miles. <s:a href="#" cssClass="ir help" >Help</s:a><!--<a class="ir help">Help</a>--></p>
                        <s:else>&nbsp;</s:else>
                        </s:if>
                    </div>
                    <!-- div id="transactionSummary" class="sub_grid_3 omega">
                        <dl>
                            <dt class="sub_grid_2 alpha">TOTAL DONATED MILES</dt>
                            <dd class="sub_grid_1 omega"><s:property value="donateMiles.donateMilesProductType.totalDonateMilesAmount" /></dd>
                            <dt class="sub_grid_2 alpha">New SkyMiles Balance</dt>
                            <dd class="sub_grid_1 omega"><s:property value="donateMiles.donateMilesProductType.memberAvailableBalance" /></dd>
                        </dl>
                        <p>We'll send a copy of this transaction to your current email address that we have on file.</p>
                    </div -->
                    <div id="transactionSummary" class="bgt-transSummary">
                        <dl>
                            <div class="row">
                                <dt>TOTAL DONATED MILES</dt>
                                <dd id="totalDonatedMiles"><s:text name="format.number"><s:param value="donateMiles.donateMilesProductType.totalDonateMilesAmount"></s:param></s:text></dd>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <dt class="bottomLine">New SkyMiles Balance</dt>
                                <dd id="totalDonatedMiles" class="bottomLine"><s:text name="format.number"><s:param value="donateMiles.donateMilesProductType.memberAvailableBalance"></s:param></s:text></dd>
                            </div>
                        </dl>
                        <div class="textSummary"><p>A confirmation email will be sent to the email address associated with the SkyMIles account.</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <!-- Defect 9945 -->
                <div class="contentWrapperFooter">
                <p id="returnToLandingPage"><a href="index.action">Return to Buy, Gift, Transfer</a></p>                
            </div>
            </div><!-- End div.content -->
        </div>      
    <script src='<s:url value="/buyGiftTransfer/js/delta.bgt.common.js"/>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <jsp:include page="/components/omniture/buyGiftTransferDonate.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <script id="renderFunction">
        $('#primaryModuleContainer').html($('#_primaryModule_loggedIn').render());
        $('#renderFunction').remove();
    </script>
    <jsp:include page="/components/omniture/buyGiftTransferDonate_errors.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <script src='<s:url value="/buyGiftTransfer/js/delta.bgt.common.js"/>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='<s:url value="/buyGiftTransfer/js/donatejs.js"/>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='<s:url value="/buyGiftTransfer/js/updateDashboardMiles.js"/>' type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS Controlling the print styles:

```
@media print {
nav#nav-widget, nav#utility-nav , .interactivebreadcrumb , footer, section{ display:none; }
.addedCharityDeets .giftedSkyMiles p.label {color:333333}
#brand a {
background:url(//int-cdn.delta.com/etc/designs/delta/images/bg-global-sprite.png) no-repeat 0 0;  
}
}
```

When I print the page it is a bunch of random characters. I have looked into character encoding and font encoding issues, but I have yet to turn up anything on here or on google. I just had my previous post closed so I am reposting. I am new to stack overflow so I wasn't sure about what I needed to provide. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked that the font the Chrome is trying to print is the same across all pages? if you are having an issue printing you may want to convert to a pdf in the intermediate step. Or collect your user's information, create a pdf and then mail it to them?

Comment: We can not use the pdf method per project requirements, because not all international users will be able to view them.

Comment: how about setting your font to something like Tahoma or Georgia and try again? That may work because you could be using a web font??

Comment: Hey that is a good idea. I will give that a shot.

Comment: Are your print styles being loaded via CDN? I had a similar problem, where Chrome was printing spaces instead of text. No other browsers were having the issue. I served the print.css from the web server instead of the CDN and it fixed the issue.